# Is the Invariant subspace subset of an eigenspace?

Tags: invariant-subspace

Let $B$ be a linear transformation.
If we found an invarient subspace say $W$ under B, does this follow that $W$ is subset of some eigenspace of $B$ ?

Comment: No, since the ambient space itself is invariant.

Comment: Okay.But can I at least find an eigenvector of $B$ in $W$ ?

Comment: Yes, if the characteristic polynomial of the restriction of $B$ to $W$ has roots in the base field (I suppose you're working with finite dimensional spaces).

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you